# Can't install a chained SSL WebAuth certificate on Cisco WLC

Tags: ssl, cisco, wlan

I have a trouble with installing StartCom's SSL certificate for WebAuth on a Cisco WLC 2504 controller. It has `7.2.103.0` software version.

I have done all the steps that are described in [Cisco's guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless/4400-series-wireless-lan-controllers/109597-csr-chained-certificates-wlc-00.html), but it says 'Error installing certificate'.Yes, I'm sure, that the order of certs is right (device, intermediate, root). Yes, I have a valid key for this certificate. I used OpenSSL version `0.9.8`, downloaded from Sourceforge as Cisco suggested. Nothing helps. I've provided the logs of TFTP transaction below.

```
Mode............................................. TFTP
Data Type........................................ Site Cert
TFTP Server IP................................... 172.16.10.5
TFTP Packet Timeout.............................. 6
TFTP Max Retries................................. 10
TFTP Path........................................ /
TFTP Filename.................................... wlc.pem

This may take some time.
Are you sure you want to start? (y/N) y
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:29.319: Memory overcommit policy changed from 0 to 1
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:29.647: Delete ramdisk for ap bundle
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:29.897: RESULT_STRING: TFTP Webauth cert transfer starting.
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:29.898: RESULT_CODE:1

TFTP Webauth cert transfer starting.
*emWeb: Oct 13 23:08:32.318: Still waiting!  Status = 2
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.906: Locking tftp semaphore, pHost=172.16.10.5 pFilename=/wlc.pem
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.907: Semaphore locked, now unlocking, pHost=172.16.10.5 pFilename=/wlc.pem
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.907: Semaphore successfully unlocked, pHost=172.16.10.5 pFilename=/wlc.pem
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.908: TFTP: Binding to remote=172.16.10.5
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.950: TFP End: 10021 bytes transferred (0 retransmitted packets)
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.951: tftp rc=0, pHost=172.16.10.5 pFilename=/wlc.pem pLocalFilename=cert.p12

*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.951: RESULT_STRING: TFTP receive complete... Installing Certificate.

TFTP receive complete... Installing Certificate.
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:33.951: RESULT_CODE:13
*emWeb: Oct 13 23:08:35.317: Still waiting!  Status = 2
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:37.953: Adding cert (9941 bytes) with certificate key password.
*emWeb: Oct 13 23:08:38.317: Still waiting!  Status = 1
*emWeb: Oct 13 23:08:41.317: Still waiting!  Status = 1
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:42.540: RESULT_STRING: Error installing certificate.
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:42.540: RESULT_CODE:12

*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:42.541: ummounting: <umount /mnt/download/ >/dev/null 2>&1>  cwd  = /mnt/application
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:42.622: finished umounting
*TransferTask: Oct 13 23:08:43.031: Create ramdisk for ap bundle
Error installing certificate.
```

It's important to say that I've did *the same* steps and sent *the same* PEM file on another WLAN controller (with `7.0.240.0` SW version) and it worked fine. So there's nothing wrong with file itself. How to fix this issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by using older version of OpenSSL. You need OpenSSL version **0.9.8h** to build the cert chain that is accepted by Cisco WLC with SW version 7.0.x